# How to measure the size of a PDF downloaded from a URL

Tags: java, filesize

I am downloading a PDF from a URL and saving it to my local drive.

The download code is working perfectly, the problem is that when I try to measure the size of the file it always claims it to be 52 bytes. I'm baffled... could you please review my code and tell me if I'am missing something?

```
try {
                 link = new URL("http://www.annualreports.co.uk/HostedData/AnnualReports/PDF/LSE_" + entry[0] + "_2015.pdf");
                 // http://www.annualreports.co.uk/HostedData/AnnualReports/PDF/LSE_BT_2015.pdf

                 InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(link.openStream());
                 ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                 byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                 int n = 0;
                 while (-1!=(n=in.read(buf)))
                 {
                    out.write(buf, 0, n);
                 }
                 out.close();
                 in.close();
                 byte[] response = out.toByteArray();

                 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
                 fos.write(response);
                 fos.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Couldn't retrieve : " + entry[1] + " " + year);
            }

            int bytes = fileName.length();
            System.out.println(bytes);
```

Comment: You seem to be measuring the length of the `fileName`, which is presumably the name of the file.

Comment: You're printing the length of the file **name**. Duh!

Comment: ah sorry guys thats was dopey. I am new to this! apologies for the amateur questions... so is there any objects in this code which would measure the file not the file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here. Just simply try this.

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.annualreports.co.uk/HostedData/AnnualReports/PDF/LSE_" + entry[0] + "_2015.pdf");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.76");
int size = conn.getContentLength();

        if (size < 0) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        } else {
            System.out.println("File size in Bytes: " + size);
        }
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Well, you can accept the answer then. :)